# Silverstripe redirects to default action with anchor links

Tags: silverstripe

After a form is submitted and handled, I want it to redirect back to the page with the form on it, with a #anchor link, like this:

```
/facility/some-facility#form
```

How is this best achieved with Silverstripe?

```
return $this->redirect($this->Link .'#form')
```

sends the browser back to

```
/facility/some-facility/Form#form
```

and redirectBack() does not take any arguments

Comment: a shot in the dark but could something like this help `$this->redirect( Controller::join_links( $this->Link(), '#'.$form->getAttribute('id') )`

Comment: ah.  you are correct!  return $this->redirect($this->Link() . '#facility-enquiry');  I was trying Link not Link() and it was appending "Form" to the path.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Colymba in the comments, the ->Link() is a method, not a property

```
return $this->redirect($this->Link() . '#facility-enquiry');
```

gives the correct redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously one option is

```
return $this->redirect($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] . "#facility-enquiry");
```

But that seems a bit basic when all the other redirection functions offer a bit of error checking etc.